# C# main thread is blocked by second thread using signaling?

Tags: c#, winforms, threadpool, autoresetevent

`GetFiles` creates the second thread which calls `CopyFiles`, I am just trying to fill the listbox with the file name each time a file is copied, but once code hits line:

```
listBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { PrintProgress(i.ToString()); }, new object[] { });
```

main thread gets blocked, any ideas?

```
void GetFiles()
{
    AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(CopyFiles),autoEvent);

    //some unrelated code

    autoEvent.WaitOne();
}

private void CopyFiles(object stateInfo)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        //SetControlPropertyValue(listBox1, i.ToString());       
        listBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { PrintProgress(i.ToString()); }, new object[] { });
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    // Signal that this thread is finished.
    ((AutoResetEvent)stateInfo).Set();     
}

private void PrintProgress(string number)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(number);
}
```

Comment: No Repro. It works on my machine.

Comment: @Albert - Have you tried not placing the main thread asleep for 1 second a chance?

Comment: Yes I did, in fact I set that only for testing but I do the actual file copy operation right there.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `WaitOne` call? Blocking the UI thread for any length of time is a terrible idea.

Comment: I added autoEvent.WaitOne(); because I wanted the main thread to wait until the CopyFiles method finished its work, since GetFiles method will use those files after autoEvent.WaitOne(); line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main thread hanged because you are calling the `GetFiles()` from it. so you have a dead lock, here is a scenario:

The main thread will block at line `autoEvent.WaitOne();` waiting for a signal to proceed, but it will never receive that signal because the signal is depending on executing a code on the main thread "`listBox1.Items.Add(number);`" and the last one will blocked waiting for `autoEvent.WaitOne()` to finish. a dead lock.

To fix that run the `GetFiles()` method from another thread rather than the main thread, so:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((_) => { GetFiles(); }), null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are synchronizing with the event on main thread, and it just can't process the invokes.

You should post the code that uses the event later in GetFiles method.

Comment: I added one important missing line to GetFiles method autoEvent.WaitOne();

Comment: So you are in a deadlock this way. Use Jalal's suggestion to run the code on separate thread